# How to disable deeplinking in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am now trying to implement a page with Angularjs.  But the problem is that the behaviour of the anchor element in the page seems to be overrided by Angularjs.

So for the below anchor element, I just want to present a link for the user to go to the destination.

```
<a href="payment/123">Pay!</a>
```

So I just want to direct the user to the page at `payment/123`.  But if I click on the link now, it just try to come out with a new url by adding the link in `href` to the current url.  Say e.g. if the current url is `http://www.example.com/shopping`, then it tries to direct me to `http://www.example.com/shopping/#/payment/123` but not what I want (`http://www.example.com/payment/123`).

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug with rc11 and rc12. Try 1.0.0 final.